# what is default downloaded path in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have given a download file url in parse method, what is the default location for that files and Is there any possibility to change that downloaded directory?

Answer (score 0):

The response contents in `parse(self, response)` method are not files and are not stored on disk. The `response` is a python object and is stored in memory.

Scrapy only downloads contents if `HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED` setting is set and it will cache all pages in `<project_root>/.scrapy` directory.

Comment: can you please explore it little bit more?